# Parsing URLs to extract an ID

Tags: php

I am currently extracting youtube video ids with the use of my function `getYoutubeId`. The function generally parses the link to find its respective ID. But I am having trouble assigning the input textbox a php variable that will then pass the `url` into the function and finally extract the ID. The video ID or Nothing at all is being echoed when pasting url into textbox. Here is an example: [Mockup SITE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/testYTvid/test.php)

```
    <input type="text" name="youtube" value="<? $sYoutubeUrl ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Parsen">


    <?

    function getYoutubeId($sYoutubeUrl) {

        # set to zero
        $youtube_id = "";
        $sYoutubeUrl = trim($sYoutubeUrl);

        # the User entered only the eleven chars long id, Case 1
        if(strlen($sYoutubeUrl) === 11) {
            $youtube_id = $sYoutubeUrl;
            return $sYoutubeUrl;
        }

        # the User entered a Url
        else {

            # try to get all Cases
            if (preg_match('~(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})~i', $sYoutubeUrl, $match)) {
                $youtube_id = $match[1];
                return $youtube_id;
            }
            # try to get some other channel codes, and fallback extractor
            elseif(preg_match('~http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?|embed\/([0-9A-Za-z-_]{11})|watch\?v\=([0-9A-Za-z-_]{11})|#.*/([0-9A-Za-z-_]{11})~si', $sYoutubeUrl, $match)) {

                for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
                    if (strlen($match[$i])==11) {
                        $youtube_id = $match[$i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return $youtube_id;
            }
            else {
                $youtube_id = "No valid YoutubeId extracted";
                return $youtube_id;
            }
        }
    }

   echo (getYoutubeId($sYoutubeUrl));

    ?>
```

Comment: where you called the function (getYoutubeId($sYoutubeUrl))?

Comment: @Akam yea I have updated my code with `(getYoutubeId($sYoutubeUrl))` called at the end

Comment: Won't all YouTube videos have an ID in the `v` parameter in the URL?

Comment: @AymanSafadi No my friend, some are like this: `http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/2/PPS-8DMrAn4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the input tags within a form, like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="youtube" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Parsen" />
</form>
```

Then check if the form has been submitted and display your info:

```
?>

if(isset($_POST['youtube'])){

  // include that function here

  print 'Result: ' . getYoutubeId($_POST['youtube']);
}
```

Consider using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get your video ID from the URL, instead of regular expressions.